# Formatting date and start countdown in jquery?

Tags: jquery, countdown, datetime-format

I created this code to format these dates. That I have an **datetime** like this:

First case:

```
<time class="fDate" data-timetype="day" datetime="2015-02-18">
```

Second case:

```
<time class="sCountdown" data-timetype="countdown" datetime="2015-02-17 19:00:00"></time>
```

The code that I have, I have checked my console and returns me the dates in this format **Wed February 18, 2015** in the first case. And I want the date in this format **Wednesday 18th February 2015** and the second case I want like this: **22 hours & 24 minutes**

I want to do is a countdown to do this:

> For ES delivery on Thursday 19th February 2015, complete this order in
>   the next 22 hours & 21 minutes, and choose Next Day Delivery at
>   checkout.

And I'm blocked in my code to do this.

[CODE IN PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGy87RTLamgjmMvTU1hz?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this snippet:

```
$(function (){
  "use strict";

  // Save finish date for free delivery
  var firstNode = $('.fDate');
  var firstDate = getDate(firstNode);
  firstNode.replaceWith(firstDate.toDateString());


  // Save start day for run the countdown
  var cdNode = $('.sCountdown');
  var cdDate = getDate(cdNode);
  var diff = (cdDate.getTime()-new Date().getTime())/1000;

  var hours = parseInt( diff / 3600 ) % 24;
  var minutes = parseInt( diff / 60 ) % 60;
  var seconds = diff % 60;
  cdNode.replaceWith(hours+' hours & '+minutes+' minutes');

});

function getDate(node){
    return new Date(Date.parse(node.attr('datetime')));
}
```

Comment: I try but I have this problem "in the next NaN hours & NaN minutes, and choose Next" for the countdown

Comment: OK, it is weird in the plunker works perfectly but if I add it to the project does not return me this error.

Comment: I made a console.log the var diff and the console returns NaN.
Html structure is the same as that in Plunker

Comment: Does the time format in the datetime attribute exact match? Date.parse is expecting a RFC2822 or ISO-8601 time format. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse Maybe you can change the format of your attribute value to match one of these two standards. It should produce better results.

Comment: I made a test and changed my value attribute and it works. Now I have to talk to the guys from backend to change the format. Because I have this value from the server.  

Thanks Simon ;)